# Install sql express 2005 and backup database on application install

Tags: c#, installation, clickonce, sql-server-express

I have a c# wpf application that requires SQL Express 2005 database and I want to deploy Sql Express with my application. So I googled but didn't find any valuable information how to create an installer that will

```
  1. install Sql Express 2005 and 
  2. restore my backup database
```

before my project installetion? I have tried to install SqlExpr.exe silently with custom actions in visual studios setup project, but it is not possible, because 2 msi installers can't run in the same time. So Is there any free and easy to use tool that supports this type of installer scripts , or I have to write custom exe that will install this all. please provide an example.

**EDIT**

Is Click Once the case? I want to have installer files in one place, and don't want installetion from the server, as click once suggests.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have similar needs in one of our installers.  Our solution was to write a "bootstrapper" exe like you mentioned.  We use the exe to shell out the sql express installation and then our own MSI sequentially.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ? I have something similar where I would like to install a SQLEXpress with a new database (from a backup or mdf whatever works) but I do not know what is a bootstrepper nor how to to it.

Comment: @David, we have a normal windows forms application that is the "bootstrapper", that exe finds files that are either embedded resources in the exe or sitting on the file system and performs silent installations.